# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined Query parameter jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

```
    function getParameterByName(topicId, url) {
       if (!url) url = window.location.href;
       topicId = topicId.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
       var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + topicId + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
           results = regex.exec(url);
       if (!results) return null;
       if (!results[2]) return '';
       return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        var topicId = getParameterByName(topicId);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'https://app.cloop.io/swish/rest/topic/' + topicId + '/basicInfo',
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json'
        }).done(function () {
            $("ol").prepend("<li>Contest ends on "+ topicId + "</li>");
        }).fail(function() {

        })
    });
```

It shows cannot read property 'replace' of undefined. I'm . getting topicId from url query parameter. It shows like this. what it would be?

Comment: `var topicId = getParameterByName('topicId')`

Comment: `var topicId = getParameterByName(topicId);` doesn't make sense. You are passing `topicId` to `getParameterByName` as an object. Are you meaning to pass it as a string? `getParameterByName('topicId')`?

Comment: Check the value of `topicId` and `results` with `console.log()` to see if their values are correct or not.

Comment: @Nope in the third line of code im getting the topicId from the url like https://www.example.com?topicId=970 so that topicId 970 im want to use it again, so I have given var topicId = getParamterByName('topicId');

Comment: @Aravind Have a look at my answer. It looks like either you forgot quotes or you redeclared an external variable (in which cas we could probably close this question as "typo").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to variable [hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) in JavaScript, when you have this at the start of your function:

```
var topicId = getParameterByName(topicId);
```

it means

```
var topicId = undefined; // any external value would be ignored
topicId = getParameterByName(topicId); // argument is undefined here
```

If you're trying to pass the value of an externally defined variable, be careful to use a different name for your local one. Because this `var` declaration shadows the external one.

It's also possible that what you want was, in fact

```
var topicId = getParameterByName("topicId"); // notice the quotes ?
```

Comment: It worked out. var topicId = getParameterByName("topicId"); this is the solution